# How to calculate the factorial of a number entered by user in Javascript, using, do-loop, while-loop?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-loops

Quick follow-up question on my previous question. I'd like to add the code to the following to calculate the factorial of a number entered by user in Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sum of Numbers</title>
 <script>
  var numbers = prompt("Enter a  number 1-100");

  while (numbers!=null && (isNaN(parseInt(numbers)) || parseInt(numbers) >100 || parseInt(numbers) <1)) {
      numbers = prompt("Try again.Enter a  number 1-100");
  }
  

  if (numbers !=null){
        alert("Finally you entered a correct number");

  var sum = 0;
  var numOfLoops = numbers;
  var counter = 1;
  do {
    sum+=counter;
    counter++;
  }

  while (counter<=numOfLoops)
  alert ("The sum of numbers from 1 to " + numbers + "is =" +sum);
}
 </script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
    document.write("<h1>Sum of Numbers</h1>");
        document.write("The sum of numbers from 1 to = " + numbers +  "&nbsp;is = "  +
            + sum + "<br><br>");
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to sum up the numbers, consider using arithmetic series formula. If you're trying to get the factorial, the approach is shown below.

If you want to sum using the loop, just change the `*=` to `+=`.

### While Loop Approach

```
const fact = (n) => {
  
let res = 1;
  
while (n > 0) {
  res *= n;
  n--;
}
  
return res;
  
}

fact(5) // 120
```

### Do While Approach

```
const fact = (n) => {
  
  let res = 1;
  
  do {
    res *= n;
    n--;
  } while (n > 0)
  
  return res;
  
}

fact(3) // 6
```

That should do the trick. :)

Maybe also considering checking for edge cases like if the n is negative.

Good luck.

Comment: `0` is not an edge case: `0! = 1`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer description. :)

Answer (score 0):

While Loop:

```
const fact=n=>
  {
  if(n<0) throw 'factorial error on a negative number!'
  let r = 1
  while(n) r *= n--
  return r
  }
```

Do While:

```
const fact=n=>
  {
  if(n<0) throw 'factorial error on a negative number!'
  let r = 1
  do  r *= n || 1 // in case of n == 0
  while (n--)
  return r;
  }
```

complete code

```js
const
  msgPrompt_1 = 'Please enter a number from 0 to 100', 
  msgPrompt_n = 'Try again.... Enter a  number 0-100',
  fact        = n =>
    {
    let r = 1
    while(n) r *= n--
    return r
    }

let numValue = parseInt(window.prompt(msgPrompt_1, ''), 10)

while(isNaN(numValue) || numValue > 100 || numValue < 0) 
  {
  numValue = parseInt(window.prompt(msgPrompt_n, ''), 10)
  }

alert(`factorial value of ${numValue} is = ${fact(numValue)}`  )
```